# How to create a self-closing HTML5 tag like <br>

Tags: html, tags

I want to basically make a custom tag that doesn't need to be closed and apply css to it.

It shouldn't look like this:`<customtag></customtag>`.

It should look like this: `<customtag>` or `<customtag/>`.

Comment: I don't agree with the close reason. There aren't many possible answers (the only correct answer is "you can't"), and a good answer only needs to address why (which is essentially "because the specs say so").

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless an element is already defined to be a [void element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#void-elements) in the HTML spec, they must have a closing tag.

Because of this, all custom web components must have a close tag. Additionally, [custom elements must have a hyphen in their names](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#concepts) to avoid conflicting with possible future tags.